# Securing a MEAN/NodeJS App without view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, security, passport.js, mean-stack

So I have written a Platform to manage exams. The exams are stored in a mongodb and accessable via REST. The view is not implemented on that server but runs on another server.js.

my Client:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen('7777');
```

and my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

var klausuren = require('./routes/klausuren');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/notenplattform');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function callback(){
  console.log("Fehler bei Verbindung zu MongoDB!");
});

db.once('open', function callback(){
  console.log("Verbindung zu MongoDB Erfoglreich!");
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/klausuren', klausuren);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

my question is: how can i secure the client and the server ? all solutions i found online require the basic setup of node JS where the view is served by the server itself not in an own client script.

I dont really know how to implement this via Passport and other solutions and an excessive use of google didnt help either. Sorry for the beginner question! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can use https://auth0.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use JWT (json web token), with this tool you can generate tokens when your users authenticate without worrying with sessions.

1. When the user tries to login you verify username/password from database
2. Generate a token for the user and send it to him
3. The user sends this token in every request that you want to be private for logged users and then you verify if it's a valid one

If you want more information take a look at [Authenticate a Node.js API with JSON Web Tokens](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) it has a simple but helpful tutorial, hope that helps.